# Mui RadioGroup validation validates only the first element

Tags: reactjs

If first gender (male) is selected then it shows the correct result, if the second gender (female) is selected it throws the error

[image]

Can you please find the issue.

App.js

```
import  { useState } from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

import {Radio,RadioGroup,FormControlLabel,FormControl,FormLabel,FormHelperText } from '@mui/material';

export default function App() {
  const {register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors } } = useForm();
  const [gender, setGender] =  useState(null);

  function handleGender(event) {
    setGender(event.target.value);
  }

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
      alert(data.gen);
  };

  return (
    <form  onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} style={{margin:20}}>
      <div className="form-group">    
        <FormControl  >
          <FormLabel  >Gender</FormLabel>
          <RadioGroup
              aria-labelledby="gender-label"
              name="gender" row
              value={gender}              
              {...register("gen", { required: 'Please select a gender' })}
              onChange={handleGender}
          >
            <FormControlLabel value="male"  control={<Radio />} label="Male"/>
            <FormControlLabel value="female" control={<Radio />} label="Female" />
          </RadioGroup>
          <FormHelperText>{errors.gen && (<div>{errors.gen.message}</div>)}</FormHelperText>
        </FormControl>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" > Submit </button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

npm used

```
npm i @mui/material      
npm install @emotion/react
npm i @emotion/styled 
npm install -f
```

Answer (score 1):

move `onchange` inside the `register`

```
{...register("gen", { required: true , onChange: (e) => {handleGender(e)}, })}
```

add the errors like this

```
  <FormHelperText>{errors.gen && (<div>Please select a gender</div>)}</FormHelperText>
```